# No response result when using RestSharp(in IIS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

This problem puzzle me so long time.

I write an asp.net project, and I use RestSharp to post my request to authorize whether user can log in the site.

Below is the code of the method of to call the authorize server

```
public static async Task<UserInfo> ValidatorResult(string userName, string passWord)
{
    var client = new RestClient(AuthUrl.BaseUrl);
    var request = new RestRequest(AuthUrl.LoginURL, Method.POST);
    //client.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
    request.AddParameter(InformationDefine.CLIENT_ID_ID, InformationDefine.CLIENT_ID);
    request.AddParameter(InformationDefine.CLIENT_SECRET_ID, InformationDefine.CLIENT_SECRET);
    request.AddParameter(InformationDefine.GRANT_TYPE_ID, InformationDefine.GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD);
    request.AddParameter(InformationDefine.MAIL_ID, userName);
    request.AddParameter(InformationDefine.PASSWORD_ID, passWord);
    var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<UserInfo>(request);
    return response?.Data;
}
```

And this is the address const of my authorize server:

```
class AuthUrl
{
    public const string BaseUrl = @"https://account.mysit.com.cn";

    public const string LoginURL = @"/api/oauth/access";
}
```

When I use these codes in my local environment, I can get the right UserInfo, but when I publish this project to IIS server, I always get 500 code when I call this method.

The error is "response?.Data" is null.

I want to solve this problem and I tried so many ways.But all failed.

I want get the reason in the IIS so I added one line code

```
client.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
```

It's so amazing that when I open the fiddler, sometimes I can get the UserInfo, but when I close fiddler, the error appeared again.

Can you tell me why?

And How to solve this problem.

Thank you.

**P.s I forgot one detail, in the IIS the binding domain of mysite is not below kinds "localhost" or "ip:port".**

**I have an another domain like "hai.xxxxx.co",  the address of my site is "hai.xxxxx.co:8088".**

Update my the binding config in iis

[image]

Comment: Should I change the config of the IIS server?

Comment: https://account.mysit.com.cn is this domain sitting in your IIS?

Comment: @ngeksyo Yes, my site is under this domain,use one port.

Comment: When you are calling the application in your server, you should use the local address (http://localhost:port) instead of the domain.

Comment: Maybe I make you misunderstand, IIS add website can binding a domain to one site, and my site is in the IIS, but the domain I only know the api address, I don't know its position.@ngeksyo

Comment: Its little difficult to get the issue from the data you have,since it is working fine in development environment and also using fiddler,can u take a network trace using the following setting added to web.config file  ? refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing) or [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saurabs/2017/06/12/system-net-tracing-collection-steps/)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the key of this problem.

Because the authorize is not from my service, so I need a reverse proxy.

It's the reason of when I open the fiddle and set proxy in the code, I can't get response normally.